# I lost the 2nd word of my seed phrase and I'm not a coder but I know the other 11 words and positions

Tags: metamask

can somebody please help, a working tip other than try all the bip-39 words manually will be rewarded via eth.  (I'm trying to claim a time sensitive airdrop)

my manual issue is i keep filling in different words in the 2nd position and 5 times now it has opened up a different wallet than mine empty of course, i'm not a thief anyways but I digress

Regards,
eric

Comment: Ultimately, bruteforcing is the only solution. Theres only 2048 words in the bip39 word list. Trying them manually is perfectly possible, probably a bit slow though. I can build you a script that would do that for you if you want, just give me contact info so we can work out the details :)

Comment: i have 2 hours to get in or i miss the airdrop worth 1250 usd so i assume not worth it for either of us but what do i know

Comment: Thats a rather short timeframe. I can give it a shot but i dont guarantee anything. My discord s in my bio, add me :)